# Postgres query needs to be able to be used in the $to for email

Tags: php, html, postgresql, email, syntax-error

I have a report that needs to go out to store managers daily.  Everything is working except the $to section that needs to call the store managers e-mail.  I know this has something to do with the single quotes that are usually around emails, but I can't get this to work properly with all the stuff I've tried.  Can someone let me know what I am missing?

```
$store_managers = $db->getOne("SELECT users.email, store_managers.store FROM users, store_managers
            WHERE users.user_id = store_managers.user_id
            AND store_managers.store = $sNum[$row]");
   if(DB::isError($store_managers)) { echo '<div class="error">Error: - '.$store_managers->getDebugInfo().'</div>';}

$to = '$store_managers';

$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $ccList1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$subject = 'This is a TEST.';

$message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'
<html><head></head><body>';
$message .= '<h3>THIS IS A TEST.</h3>';
$message .= '<br /><h5>'.$store_managers.'</h5>';
```

NOTE: The message syntax used at the end is not working for the `$to` field. I keep getting a dead.letter... Message saved in etc.

Comment: Syntax errors are bad m'kay. Enable error reporting and start using an editor with syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something obviously wrong in this code in relation with `$to` is this line:

```
$to = '$store_managers';
```

Because when surrounded by single quotes, the `$store_managers` variable is not interpolated. You don't want these single quotes, do that instead:

```
$to = $store_managers;
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked. I guess with all the lists I have been building I managed to forget some of the basics.